# How can you migrate an entity framework project to .NET standard when the fluent configuration is using HasDatabaseGeneratedOption

Tags: c#

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.1 class library that contains my repository layer. We are building an ASP.NET Core API and want to access the existing repository in the short term to cut down on migration work. We are migrating the repository library to a .NET Standard 2.0 class library. The repository layer is using Entity Framework 6.2 and is using fluent configuration for the entities. The challenge I am experiencing is that we have several places where we are using DatabaseGeneratedOption, which is defined in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, which is a Framework library that doesn't seem to be available to .NET Standard.

There is a NuGet package System.ComponentModel.Annotations, but it doesn't seem to help. Is there a way I can preserve the DatabaseGeneratedOption configuration or will I need to drop it and hope that Entity Framework correctly guesses the configuration from the DB structure?

Configuration that doesn't work would look something like this:

```
HasKey(e => e.Id)
.Property(e => e.Id)
.HasColumnName("Id")
.HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier")
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None
)
.IsRequired();
```

Comment: So the solution is that EF 6.2 won't work in a .NET Standards 2.0 class library. You need to create a .NET Framework class library due to EF 6.2 framework dependencies. You can reference a .NET Framework class library from a .netcoreapp. You just lose cross platform ability. If you need cross platform use EF Core. Not sure if EF 6.3 gets around this. The answer below didn't solve my specific issue because I am using fluent config in separate configuration class, not attribute config in entity. I also didn't want an MVC library reference in my repo library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I used a .NET Framework class library (I am using v4.7.2 as the Target Framework Version) for my EF 6.2 repository layer. EF 6.2 doesn't work in netstandard2.0 class libraries due to missing .NET Framework dependencies (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager and migrations).

A .NET Core app can reference a .NET Framework class library if you set its target framework to .net framework (net472 for example), although you lose cross platform capability. If you need cross platform, you can use EF Core, although this won't work for us in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity you can do this:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

This requires **using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** from this:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations" Version="2.2.0" />
```